# How can I handle a wrong argument value in a custom method?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a class with a `SortelList` as private field: each element of this list has a `string` as key and custom data as value. When I call the `Update` method of my class, I specify the key and the data, and:

- if the list doesn't contain the specified key, then a new entry is added to the list;
- otherwise, the current data are updated with the specified data (so no exception is thrown).

  ```
  public class Cache
  {
      private SortedList<string, Data> _list;

      // ... constructors and other methods

      public void Update(string key, Data value, int number)
      {
          Data data;
          if (this._list.TryGetValue(key, out data))
          {
              // update data using value and number
              //
              // ...

              _list[key] = data;   // overwrite the previous data with the updated data
          }
          else
          {
              _list.Add(key, value);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

As a consequence, this class never throw an exception, even if you specify a duplicate key. But the value of `number` argument must be positive, then the values ​​less than or equal to zero should be ignored. What is the better way to exclude these values?

- I could ignore values ​​less than or equal to zero: `if (number <= 0) return;`
- I could make the `Update` method return a bool, so: `if (number <= 0) return false;`
- I could make the `Update` method throw an exception when the number in not positive.

Comment: If negatives are allowed and should just be ignored then just ignore. If negatives are an error, either eliminate the possibility by making number unsigned, use code contracts to ensure it or throw an exception.

Comment: IMHO There seems to be no "better way" to di this  all option you think of are viable, all depends on the behavior you prefer from the code.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Don't forget that the max value of a uint is twice that of an int so if you use that you would still have to check that it is less than int.MaxValue or you could run into errors later on if you try and cast the value to an int. Also it would still allow zero.

Comment: Only positive values are allowed. Negative values and zero ​​are meaningless within the `Update` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would throw an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx), like this:

```
public void Update(string key, Data value, int number)
{
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("number must be positive");
    }
    // Rest of the method
}
```

This is the pattern followed by the vast majority of the .Net framework when validating arguments.

The alternative would be to have the `Update` method return a boolean value indicating whether or not the operation succeeded.  This is useful in order to allow users of your API to call the method without an exception being thrown (like with the `TryParse` methods), however in this case there is no need as users of the method can already trivially avoid having exceptions thrown simply by checking the value of the `number` argument before calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you have a number of options, I would suggest that you either change the return value to bool and return false to state that it is not updated or throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

The benefit to the return false is obviously that no exception is thrown, however the consumer will have to confirm that the update happened or they will be confused when the access the value and find that it has not updated.

If you go with the exception method, you can add an xml comment to the method to state that an exception can be thrown if the number zero or lower. This would show up in the tool tip and object browser in visual studio so that the consumer know this can happen.

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates the value in the cache for the supplied key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key in the cache.</param>
/// <param name="number">The the number to store.</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown if number is less than 1.</exception>
public void Update(string key, Data value, int number)
```

Comment: The main application (which uses the `Cache` class) should ignore any wrong parameters, because negative values and zero are meaningless in the problem domain. The user of the main application should continue to use the application without it showing error messages: any wrong values could be placed in a log file.